# How to get 'All Upright' ribbon for Food Fight level 8 (Nemesisters)?

Tags: achievements, ios, bag-it

In the recent level pack "Food Fight" for Bag It, I managed to complete level 8, but one of the ribbons is for 'All Upright'. I can't find a way to get everything in upright due to the awkward shape of the bananas.

For reference, the items are:

- 3x melon
- 4x milk
- 2x salsa
- 2x green banana (L shape)
- 1x pink banana (J shape)

And the bananas cannot touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to have the milk on the side (2 on the left and 2 on the right) with the 3 melons in the middle then on the top separate the bananas with the salsas. See video below :

Comment: Thanks, that's great! My Google-fu must be off today as I couldn't find any references/walkthroughs for these levels at all!